# Replacing Is Null Or Exist Inner Query Logic to Reduce Stored Procedure Execution Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My stored procedure is currently using `Is Null Or Exist` logic combined with an inner query to filter out the records. The stored procedure is converting multiple comma-separated input values to temp tables (in the production scenario, the input record  count will be much higher). And the inner query is using these temp tables for filter conditions. Due to the concern over query execution time would like to change the existing inner-query with an alternate (like left join). But need to retain the same `Is Null Or Exist` logic. Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @SelectedOfferes varchar(1000) = 'FLT10,SPL20'
DECLARE @SelectedBrandCode varchar(1000) = '208,406'
DECLARE @CategoryCode varchar(1000) = 'GMOVN2,CELSMR,LCDTV38IN'

CREATE TABLE #SelectedOfferes 
(
    DiscountCode VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #BrandCode
(
    BrandCode VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #CategoryCode
(
    CategoryCode VARCHAR(20)
)

IF @SelectedOfferes IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #SelectedOfferes
        SELECT part 
        FROM dbo.[FormatTextByDelimiter] (@SelectedOfferes, ',')
END

IF @SelectedBrandCode IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #BrandCode
        SELECT part 
        FROM dbo.[FormatTextByDelimiter] (@SelectedBrandCode, ',')
END

IF @CategoryCode IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #CategoryCode
        SELECT part 
        FROM dbo.[FormatTextByDelimiter] (@CategoryCode, ',')
END

SELECT *    
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN Discount D ON P.DiscountCode = D.DiscountCode
INNER JOIN AvailableBrand AB ON P.BrandCode = AB.BrandCode
INNER JOIN Category C ON P.CategoryCode = C.CategoryCode
WHERE (@SelectedOfferes IS NULL 
       OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #SelectedOfferes OFR 
                   WHERE OFR.DiscountCode = P.DiscountCode)))
  AND (@SelectedBrandCode IS NULL 
       OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #BrandCode BC 
                   WHERE BC.BrandCode = P.BrandCode)))
  AND (@CategoryCode IS NULL 
       OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #CategoryCode CAT 
                   WHERE CAT.CategoryCode = P.CategoryCode)))
```

Comment: So what is your concern exactly, can you share the actual execution plan via [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) for a poor-performing example? How many rows are typically in the temp tables? Have you considered unique clustered indexes on the temp tables?

Comment: Also is `select *` just for your question or is that your true criteria?

Comment: `select *` is just for the question, actual need  is  to replace the inner query :)

Comment: I don't think you want to **increase** the execution time (e.g. make the time it takes **longer**) - you most likely want to **improve** (e.g. shorten / lessen) the execution time - right?

Comment: Consider using dynamic sql to eliminate multiple ORs.

Comment: The title was the same all along - it said "increase" from the beginning (ever since your original posting) ...

Comment: @marc_s My mistake, thank you for correcting the post.

Comment: Is this procedure expected output one row or a small set of rows?  If so, SQL may be trying to do all those inner joins first, only to join with the one row in question submitted to the stored proc.  If so, you could definitely alter the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dynamic SQL version**

I have some questions about your string split function, is it set-based or a looping query? If it's not set-based then you should probably replace it with Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K available at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ .

The below example should work the same as what you supplied but should be faster since it removes the ORs and the correlated subqueries from the WHERE clause.  I'm not a fan of using dynamic SQL but sometimes it is the best way to get the job done.  Maybe someone else can come up with a non-dynamic solution that works as well or better.

```
DECLARE @SelectedOfferes varchar(1000) = 'FLT10,SPL20'
DECLARE @SelectedBrandCode varchar(1000) = '208,406'
DECLARE @CategoryCode varchar(1000) = 'GMOVN2,CELSMR,LCDTV38IN'

CREATE TABLE #SelectedOfferes 
(
    DiscountCode VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #BrandCode
(
    BrandCode VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #CategoryCode
(
    CategoryCode VARCHAR(20)
)

IF @SelectedOfferes IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #SelectedOfferes
        SELECT part 
        FROM dbo.[FormatTextByDelimiter] (@SelectedOfferes, ',')
END

IF @SelectedBrandCode IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #BrandCode
        SELECT part 
        FROM dbo.[FormatTextByDelimiter] (@SelectedBrandCode, ',')
END

IF @CategoryCode IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #CategoryCode
        SELECT part 
        FROM dbo.[FormatTextByDelimiter] (@CategoryCode, ',')
END

DECLARE @SQL NVarchar(4000);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT *    
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN Discount D ON P.DiscountCode = D.DiscountCode
INNER JOIN AvailableBrand AB ON P.BrandCode = AB.BrandCode
INNER JOIN Category C ON P.CategoryCode = C.CategoryCode'

IF @SelectedOfferes IS NOT NULL
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'
INNER JOIN #SelectedOfferes OFR ON OFR.DiscountCode = P.DiscountCode';

IF @SelectedBrandCode IS NOT NULL
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'
INNER JOIN #BrandCode BC ON BC.BrandCode = P.BrandCode';

IF @CategoryCode IS NOT NULL
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'
INNER JOIN #CategoryCode CAT ON CAT.CategoryCode = P.CategoryCode';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

**This method doesn't quite do what the OP wanted but is valid in many other cases**

I have some questions about your string split function, is it set-based or a looping query?  If it's not set-based then you should probably replace it with Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K available at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ .

But either way the below change to your last query should help quite a bit.  The IS NULL parts aren't needed since it is a LEFT JOIN and the table will be empty if the variable it is built with is NULL, so you get the same result with less work for the engine.

```
SELECT *    
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN Discount D ON P.DiscountCode = D.DiscountCode
INNER JOIN AvailableBrand AB ON P.BrandCode = AB.BrandCode
INNER JOIN Category C ON P.CategoryCode = C.CategoryCode
LEFT JOIN #SelectedOfferes OFR ON OFR.DiscountCode = P.DiscountCode
LEFT JOIN #BrandCode BC ON BC.BrandCode = P.BrandCode
LEFT JOIN #CategoryCode CAT ON CAT.CategoryCode = P.CategoryCode
```

Comment: Actually this may not do what you want as it will not limit the output if the variable is not NULL.  I'm thinking that a dynamic SQL solution may work best in that case.  I'll work on adding that.

Comment: Added a  `WHERE` along with the left join and it is working similar to the `IS NULL OR EXISTS` logic. And there is a significant reduction in execution time. But the dynamic version of the query is comparatively faster.
`WHERE       (@SelectedOfferes IS NULL OR OFR.DiscountCode IS NOT NULL)`. Thank you